Trying to send a string from Unity to rust library, but receivies random constant bytes
I have the following rust code, receiving a string:
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum LicenseState {
    ERROR = 0,
    INVALID = 1,
    INACTIVE = 2,
    ACTIVATED = 3
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct LicenseResponse {
    pub state: u8,
    pub msg: *mut c_char
}


#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn is_license_active(s: *const c_char) -> LicenseResponse {

    let license_key;
    unsafe {
        match s.as_ref() {
            None => {
                license_key = "null".to_string()
            },
            Some(_s) => {
                let c_str = CStr::from_ptr(s);
                    license_key = format!(
                    "Received: {bytes:x?};",
                    bytes=c_str.to_bytes()
                ).to_string();

            }
        }
    }

    return LicenseResponse {
        state: 0,
        msg: CString::new(format!(
            "Key: {license_key};",
            license_key=license_key
        )).expect("CString::new failed!").into_raw()
    };
}

It is called from Unity by this code:
public static class LicensingWrapper
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct LicenseResponse
    {
        public byte state;
        public string msg;
    }
    
    [DllImport("license_validation", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern IntPtr is_license_active([byte[] s);
    
    public static void IsLicenseActive(string licenseKey)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(licenseKey))
        {
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log($"Checking key: {licenseKey}");
        byte[] bArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (licenseKey + "\0");

        var responseRaw = is_license_active(bArray);
        
        LicenseResponse response = Marshal.PtrToStructure<LicenseResponse>(responseRaw);

        Debug.Log($"Response state: {(int) response.state}; response message: {response.msg}");
    }
}

Above code is already reduced version that just trying to check what is incoming. Before it was just failing with not valid utf-8 string. Sending string back from rust to unity works flawlessly.
The problem is - I am not receiving the stuff that I am sending. Every time I send a string - no matter the length of the string, I receive some sort of garbage. It is always 6 hex values, they are totally random and the values persist until Unity is restarted.
I tried sending string with marchalling at first (with MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)), I tried constructing from raw_parts (it just crashes in this scenario), I tried sending exact bytes from code.
I am expecting getting string value, that I sent, but something is wrong and I can not find or see what.

A string is almost certainly not an alias for a raw character pointer, is it? And your C# side documenting the return type as IntPtr raises other eyebrows.

@cdhowie i am returning pointer to rust struct that is marshaled on receiving. At least no issues with getting this struct on unity side were noticed.

@alexanderfedorov Your Rust function does not return a pointer/reference to a struct though, it returns the struct itself. This is not the same thing at all.

@kmdreko I see what you mean now -- you're talking about the string in the returned struct. I missed that detail.

@cdhowie hm, indeed. I am sure I was following guides though. Might be just lucky that it is working as it is, will change it when back in the office. Not sure it will help with unity->rust string passing, though

@cdhowie maybe you will not believe it or maybe will, but fixing return code fixed issue with passed arguments. Thank you! I spent several days looking to the wrong direction :)
